# How to use php to determine the site root inside href

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, href, prefix

I would like to be able to determine the root of my website using php, so I can switch between relative and absolute links for local and online testing with ease.

e.g. instead of changing `href="/css/style.css"` to `href="http://example.com/css/style.css"`

Could I use php to call in the site root?

Edit: Originally tried this with Sass & Css, but seemed like the wrong way of going about it.

Comment: do you mean within your sass file?

Comment: ah, silly mistake, the problem is that I'm putting the variable in html. Is there any way I can do this within Sass such as using a selector to prefix the `/css/style.css"` in `href`.

Comment: Are you using a server side language e.g. php? if so, it's pretty easy to assign a variable `$rootPath="http://myUrl.com";` then change url to `href="<?=$rootPath?>/css/style.css"`

Comment: Don't do this with SASS

Comment: @DarrenSweeney that sounds perfect, you should write this as an answer as I have amended the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using a scripting language such as PHP.

At the top of your html page

```
<?PHP
    $pageRoot = "http://localhost:8080"; // for example
    // $pageRoot = "http://myUrl.com"; // commented out as we're local testing first
?>
```

Then to call your css files change the href to:

```
href="<?=$pageRoot?>"/css/style.css"
```

Then simply comment out the local host and un-comment the proper url when on your remote server

Comment: Additionally I've used Sass variables to determine the site root in my CSS like this: `.class { background-image: url(#{$rootPath}/images/img.jpg); }` and `$rootPath: "http://example.com"` (or leave it blank for relative links). By changing two variables (one php, and one Sass) I can alter the location of my site root and switch between relative and absolute links with ease (with some exceptions where header.php is not included on the page).